# Converting Audio To Video Output and Attaching Text?

Tags: video, audio, youtube

I am currently working on a project and before I get started I thought it'd be nice to check with StackOverflow community, and see maybe they can help me with this.

The Idea: I have about a thousand MP3 files that I need to convert into video files to be upload on Youtube for my work. I need to also attach the text associated with the audio to the video as an image. I was thinking .ppt.

The Problem: I can do this one audio file at a time but it would take me a zillion years.

**The Question**: Can I create some kind of program using (for example) XML or JavaScript or XHTML or some other programming language to do a MASS content creation and all I have to do is feed it the information? Or is it possible to create an example .ppt file and then hack it so that I can have it reproduce itself with different information??

Comment: The answer is yes. Does that answer help you? I doubt it.  That's because the question is *way* to broad to be answerable in it's current form. My suggestion is that you Google a bit, I'm pretty confident you'll find that someone else has done this before you.

Comment: Thanks Nifle...I have done alot of research but couldn't find anything remotely close. Maybe i am looking in the wrong places but i'll give another go at it....and also try to construct a better question.

Comment: Are you looking for automatic transcription or manual transcription?  Automatic transcription will probably not be very accurate, with many errors.  Or are you just asking how to convert the text to video?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what 15 minutes of googling turned up.
It will turn `img.png`  and `audio.mp3`<sup>**1**</sup> into `result.avi` using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -shortest -y -i img.png -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -vcodec mpeg4 result.avi
```

It looks pretty crappy but I haven't tweaked the options one bit, the ffmpeg documentation is **vast**. But that's not the point I'm trying to make. This works and with some shell scripting and tweaking of ffmpeg options you should be able to do what you want.

My suggestion is, get ffmpeg get it to produce a video you are satisfied with. When that is done we'll (probably) be happy to help you with the task of automating it.

<sup>**1**</sup>[(from here)](http://www.danosongs.com/blog/legal-mp3-download-for-youtube-videos-creative-commons-song-magic-ghost/)